# Using private API to enable hotspot in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi, hotspot

I am using an iOS runtime header to enable the hotspot in iOS:
[Link](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers)

```
NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Sharing.framework"];
    BOOL success = [b load];
Class SFRemoteHotspotSession=NSClassFromString(@"SFRemoteHotspotSession");
```

How do I implement the following method to enable the hotspot?

```
- (void)enableHotspotForDevice:(id)arg1 withCompletionHandler:(id /* block */)arg2;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a hotspot network in iOS app using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517727/how-to-create-a-hotspot-network-in-ios-app-using-swift)