# How to create a hotspot network in iOS app using Swift

Tags: swift, hotspot, nehotspothelper

I want to create a hotspot network in iOS app using Swift, and only Apple-approved APIs.

Comment: Provide some code you had tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NEHotspotHelper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspothelper) is an official API to do exactly this kind of stuff. Though the API is not an 'Open to All' kind. It needs the entitlement 'com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotHelper' to be included in your app.  To use this entitlement you need to ask for a permission from Apple to use this class with your app's bundle identifier with a clear reason for why you need it with some other details of your app. Use [this](https://developer.apple.com//contact/network-extension/) link to apply for the entitlement. Once apple sends an approval mail to you, you are good to go!

Comment: Can I create a test app, before actually get the entitlement approved by apple

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible for you to use this entitlement before Apple's approval. You need to get the approval first.

Comment: Thanks, actually I already tried but the code was not working

Comment: Do you have any sample by which we can create a hotspot network, I read somewhere that this is not possible. Can you confirm?

Comment: You may try [this](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2016/11/02/working-with-nehotspothelper/). There are many other articles available on this topic.

Comment: That doesnt seem to have the info. Theres stuff on *joining* a Hotspot, but not creating one.