# create hotspot programmatically on iOS using swift

Tags: ios, swift, hotspot

I'm using swift 4.2. I want to create personal hotspot on my iOS device(iPhone) but not finding any solution to this. I Read on another blog that Apps are not allowed to access settings like bluetooth, wifi and personal hotspot is it true??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517727/how-to-create-a-hotspot-network-in-ios-app-using-swift

see this ans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create hotspot programmatically.

The only way to create hotspot in iOS is to go to setting and do it manually.

> iOS is always conscious about the users private data and the user
>   settings so if you are changing any type of any settings the user
>   should be informed and user should on his own should turn off/on the
>   the settings like WiFi/hotspot or anything which is related to the
>   setting of the user in the settings menu.